# DynamoDB conditional update using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, updates, aws-sdk

how do i conditional update item in dynamoDB using nodejs?  If exists, just do an increment alone - it is working as expected. But I am struggling in, when the item is not exists, need to add it and next iteration onwards do increment. got this error "***The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item***".

```
function increment(data, cb) {
    const opt = {
        Key: {
            id: {S: id},
            dateKey: {S: data.dateVal}
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':counter': {N: '' + 1},
            ':val1': {S: data.val1},
            ':val2': {S: data.val2}
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'SET counter=counter+:counter, val1=:val1, val2=:val2',ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
        TableName:tableName
    };

    db.updateItem(opt, (err, data) => {
        if (err)
            return cb(err);

        const counter = getCounter(data.Attributes); //private method
        return cb(null, counter);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the item you are incrementing does not exist, you can assume the initial value to be 'zero' as shown bellow:

```
const opt = {
    Key: {
        id: {S: id},
        dateKey: {S: data.dateVal}
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':counter': {N: '' + 1},
        ':val1': {S: data.val1},
        ':val2': {S: data.val2},
        ':zero': {N: 0}
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET counter=if_not_exists(counter, :zero)+:counter, val1=:val1, val2=:val2',ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
    TableName:tableName
};
```